# Headers don't exist in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I imported a CSV file with read_csv(). When i use the colnames(). The column "R1_Cost" appears as it should.

```
colnames(AustinParPulse)
[1] "Respondent"      "Employed"        "StayHome"        "R1_Cost"
```

However, when I use the

```
exists("R1_Cost")
[FALSE]
```

I have also used the

```
read.csv("AustinParPulse.csv", headers = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

but I still get

```
exists("R1_Cost")
[FALSE]
```

Even when i put in

```
exists(AustinParPulse$R1_Cost)
```

[FALSE]

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: `?exists` - "Look for an R object of the given name and possibly return it". You don't have an object named `R1_Cost`. But you do have a column of that name, as shown by `colnames`. So the issue is that `exists` is not used to check column names.

Comment: I won't mention `attach(AustinParPulse) exists("R1_Cost")` because it's pure evil.

Comment: how do i make it an object? that will make it easier to code R1_Cost vs AustinParPulse$R1_Cost

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to make it a separate object to do whatever it is you want to do. But you probably do need to learn how to work with data frames, it's pretty fundamental to R.

Comment: @neilfws, you are right. I thought that when i load the csv file, it because a dataframe. do i need to make it a data frame after loading the csv file?

Comment: @LuisPabloMartinez no, it is a data frame (or if you used `read_csv`, a special type of data frame). `class(AustinParPulse)` tells you what it is.

Comment: @neilfws, yes the class(AustinParPulse) shows its data.frame. However, when i code e.g.    Stress <- data.frame(R1_Cost, R2_Avail, R3_Time) I get an error message    Error in data.frame(R1_Cost, R2_Avail, R3_Age) : 
  object 'R1_Cost' not found

Comment: @LuisPabloMartinez  To get to the R1_Cost data, you need to use `AustinParPulse$R1_Cost`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exists("R1_Cost")` will check if there is a variable named "R1_Cost" which there is not. You might imagine that you could use `exists("AustinParPulse$R1_Cost")` but that does not work either, because that is looking for a variable with the name ("AustinParPulse$R1_Cost") and there is none.  To do what you are trying to do,  you need to use the `where` argument to exists

```
 exists("R1_Cost", where=AustinParPulse)
```

Answer (score 1):

The headers do exist. Your first command, `colnames`, tells you so.

`exists` is used for a different purpose: to determine whether an object with the given variable name is present in the current environment. In your case for example, `exists(AustinParPulse)` is `TRUE`.

The column names are variable names with respect to the data frame, not objects in the environment.